# Turn a dumb sensor into I2C

Tags: i2c

I’m building a device that requires 60+ serial distance sensors spread out a great distance, all communicating back to a central controller.

I could go with existing I2C distance sensors, but my options there are limited, expensive and (possibly) overkill for what I need.

To get data from 60 cheap IR distance sensors into an arduino or similar along a serial line, it seems I will need a microcontroller for each sensor to get its data onto the bus at the right time.

Is this right? Or is there a cheaper/better way to turn 60 dumb sensors into one smart sensor, without requiring 60 wires all coming back into one controller?

Comment: A low end MCU isn't a bad idea, but you might want to consider something like multi-drop serial (via tristate) instead of I2C.  You can potentially even make it half duplex using a single data wire.  If you want to get *really* fancy you can probably multiplex it with power, eg look at one wire or the DCC stuff the model train people do.

Comment: There are plenty of low-cost, low pin count MCUs out there that would be ideal for such a task. For example, see the [3-cent microcontroller series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r45r4rV5JOI&list=PLvOlSehNtuHsiF93KOLoF1KAHArmIW9lC) on EEVblog.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “great distance” but you may need something like CAN to handle the long bus wires. I believe MCUs with CAN ports have arbitration built in for data collisions.

Comment: Sounds like you want 1 wire not i2c. I2c os meant for on a board not over long wires.

Comment: i came across this a few months back ... looks promissing ... should work with ATtiny85 ... have not tested though ... https://www.pjon.org/SoftwareBitBang.php

Comment: Thanks guys, I’ll look into everything mentioned. As for my “great distance”, I just meant that I don’t want to be running 60+ wires all the way back to the controller. They will be spread out over 100 feet or so, each on an individual custom printed board joined to the others by jumper cables, which is why I’m trying to reduce the number of cables.

Answer (score 1):

If each sensor has a small micro controller you can have them addressable via UART.
All sitting in RX mode until they get their addressed command, and then they respond.
Pretty standard method.

To be clear, the sensors would all be "daisy chained" together in parallel, power, ground RX and TX.

**UPDATE:**
The max distance for both I2C and RS232 (or any transmission really) depends on the cable capacitance.  The maximum cable length is 50 feet, or the cable length equal to a capacitance of 2500 pF.  Using CAT5 cable you get this:

```
RS232 cable length according to Texas Instruments
Baud rate   Maximum cable length (ft)
19200        50
9600         500
4800         1000
2400         3000
```

https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/rs-232-specs

You haven't mentioned baud rate requirements, but 500ft @ 9600 looks pretty good.

Also, RS232 drivers are push-pull whereas I2C is only pull down with a resistor pull up.  So it degrades faster with a cables capacitance, unless you lower the pull up resistance which increases power draw.

If you need faster baud rate, then you can look at **RS-485** (differential) instead.  It pretty much the same from the CPU perspective, you just use a different driver chip.

Comment: You’re recommending UART instead of I2C? The total distance will be around 100 feet, with the 60 sensors sprinkled throughout, each on a custom printed board joined to the others serially via jumper cables. Is 100ft too long for i2c? The sensors are for real-time interaction with the piece via gesture detection, but I imagine either protocol will consistently get the 60 signals back to the main controller fast enough for that.

Comment: @MikeMiller are you sure you can't do this with a video camera or something like a kinect?

Comment: @Aaron a *multi-drop* scheme may well be dominated by the loads, not the cable

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree. It all depends on the interface he selects.

Comment: @MikeMiller 100 feet is way too long for I2C. Even though 128 addresses are possible, 60 devices may be too much as well due to capacitive loading on TOP of the that of the long cable. All this limits speed, and the fact I2C uses a master clock limits your speed even if none of the above were issues since the clock pulse must be slow enough that a pulse can travel from master-to-slave, slave to process, and slave to send another pulse back to the master, all within the same clock cycle.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can (and probably will) use a kinect for a similar project I have in mind, but this one is to light up stairs when you step on them. Each stair will have its own board that includes the LED and the sensor (and, as it is sounding like is necessary, a small microcontroller), all connected to the controller at one end.

Comment: Why do you need to centralize it at all?

Comment: So I can program it to do fun things when someone starts walking up or down the stairs, for example. Or so I can make it play an associated note from a central speaker when a step is stepped on. I want the hardware to support whatever ideas I come up with over time, not just static rules like "turn blue when stepped on"